# 409 error with apache htaccess rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have these htaccess rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# 301 externally redirect all .php extensioned requests to extensionless
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^contact$ /?modal=contact [NC,L]

# if x.php is a file, internally add .php to x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Which can take any of these...

```
http://www.example.com/contact
http://www.example.com/contact.php
http://example.com/contact
http://example.com/contact.php
https://www.example.com/contact
https://www.example.com/contact.php
https://example.com/contact
https://example.com/contact.php
```

... and return: `https://example.com/?modal=contact`

Note that these rules also internally resolve links like `https://example.com/page` to `https://example.com/page.php` so the user will see the URL without the extension.

Although I see the desired result in the browser with a link such as `https://www.example.com/contact.php`, there's a 409 error. What's causing it?

NOTES:

- I see the 409 error in Google Search Console and at wheregoes.com
- I see only two 301 statuses in Chrome DevTools.
- The raw access server logs do show a 409 before the 301, but I don't understand why.

Here are the server entries from requesting `https://example.com/contact.php`:

```
IP.AD.RE.SS - - [22/Sep/2022:10:27:31 -0500] "GET /contact.php HTTP/2.0" 409 83 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" example.com IP.AD.RE.SS2
IP.AD.RE.SS - - [22/Sep/2022:10:27:31 -0500] "GET /contact.php HTTP/2.0" 301 235 "https://example.com/contact.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" example.com IP.AD.RE.SS2
IP.AD.RE.SS - - [22/Sep/2022:10:27:31 -0500] "GET /contact HTTP/2.0" 301 246 "https://example.com/contact.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" example.com IP.AD.RE.SS2
IP.AD.RE.SS - - [22/Sep/2022:10:27:31 -0500] "GET /?modal=contact HTTP/2.0" 200 5242 "https://example.com/contact.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" example.com IP.AD.RE.SS2
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed post, could you please do mention on hitting which URL you are getting 409? And which are working fine? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Hi there. It's at the end of my post. The 409 error is resulting from ```https://www.example.com/contact.php```

Comment: When I google it I get like: `A 409 error usually occurs in response to a PUT request. This request updates the target resource. You can use a PUT request to make a new resource or replace an existing one. However, if there are conflicting values in the PUT payload, they can cause a 409 error.` for information on 409 Error code.

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve this using https://wheregoes.com/ and I've found that the 301 external redirection is not working. I don't know why!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - This isn't a PUT request, so I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Honestly I never got this error hence I went with definition. So you get this error on browser? OR your URL is working fine but you are seeing these errors in Logs?

Comment: I see the error in Google Search Console and at wheregoes.com

Comment: "I see only two 301 statuses in Chrome DevTools." and presumably a bunch of 200 OK status? "Although I see the desired result in the browser with a link such as https://www.example.com/contact.php, there's a 409 error." - so, you DO see a 409 response in the browser or not? You need to check your server access logs for these 409 responses... the request method, user-agent and time etc. when these responses occur, to help further diagnose the problem.

Comment: @MrWhite - Thanks for the suggestion to review the server access logs. I've shared the result above. I can see the 409 error first, followed by two 301s, and then 200. This tells me what's happening, but I don't know how to prevent the 409.

Comment: You are missing the `L` flag on all your redirect directives. You _need_ the `L` flag on these rules to prevent further processing. _Aside:_ Presumably you are not actually linking to the `.php` file in your HTML source? Why are you "redirecting" to `/?modal=contact` - should that not be an internal rewrite?

Comment: @MrWhite - That's right, I'm not linking to .php in the HTML source but using extensionless links, and the modal redirect shouldn't have been 301 and should have the L flag. I've updated the code above. I'm still getting the 409 error though.

Comment: Have you added the `L` flag on the redirects as well? (It's not showing in your updated code.) All the `RewriteRule` directives need the `L` flag.

Comment: @MrWhite - Thank you. I have added the L flag everywhere and updated the code above to reflect it. Unfortunately, I'm still seeing the 409 error.

Comment: This is still an open issue. I'd love to figure this out.